# Unable to index x-axis of bokeh line chart with timestamps

Tags: python, pandas, plot, bokeh

I have been trying to make a bokeh line chart, however I am running into the issue of indexing the x-axis with a column of time stamps from my pandas data frame. Currently my data frame looks like this:

```
           TMAX TMIN  TAVG        DAY   NUM
2007-04-30   65   46  55.5 2007-04-30     1
2007-05-01   75   45  60.0 2007-05-01     2
2007-05-02   66   52  59.0 2007-05-02     3
2007-05-03   65   43  54.0 2007-05-03     4
2007-05-04   61   45  53.0 2007-05-04     5
2007-05-05   65   43  54.0 2007-05-05     6
2007-05-06   77   51  64.0 2007-05-06     7
2007-05-07   89   66  77.5 2007-05-07     8
2007-05-08   91   56  73.5 2007-05-08     9
2007-05-09   83   48  65.5 2007-05-09    10
2007-05-10   68   47  57.5 2007-05-10    11
2007-05-11   65   46  55.5 2007-05-11    12
2007-05-12   63   43  53.0 2007-05-12    13
2007-05-13   65   46  55.5 2007-05-13    14
2007-05-14   71   46  58.5 2007-05-14    15
....
[3592 rows x 5 columns]
```

I want to index the line plot with the values of the "DAY" column, however, I get an error no matter the approach I take. The documentation for line plots says that "x (str or list(str), optional) – specifies variable(s) to use for x axis". My code is as follows:

```
xyvalues = np.array([df['TAVG'], df_reg['ry'], df['DAY']])
regr = Line(data=xyvalues, x='DAY', title="Linear Regression of Data", ylabel="Average Daily Temperature", xlabel="Number of Days")
output_file("regression.html")
show(regr)
```

This gives me the error "TypeError: Cannot compare type 'Timestamp' with type 'float64'". I have tried converting it to float, but it doesn't seem to have an effect. Any help would be much appreciated. The df_reg['ry'] is data from a linear regression data frame.

Documentation for line graphs can be found here: http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/charts.html#line

Comment: It seems you neeed concat both dataframes together by `df1 = pd.concat([df[['TAVG', 'DAY']], df_reg['ry']], axis=1)` and then use `regr = Line(data=df1, x='DAY', title="Linear Regression of Data", ylabel="Average Daily Temperature", xlabel="Number of Days")`. If it does not work, what is `df_reg['ry'].head()` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside `Line`, you need to pass a `pandas` data frame to the `data` argument in order to be able to refer to your variable `DAY` for the x axis ticks. Here I create a new pandas `DataFrame` from the other two:

```
import pandas as pd
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=dict(TAVG=df['TAVG'], ry=df_reg['ry'], DAY=df['DAY']))
regr = Line(data=df2, x='DAY',
                 title="Linear Regression of Data",
                 ylabel="Average Daily Temperature",
                 xlabel="Number of Days")
output_file("regression.html")
show(regr)
```